# почему не работает этот код, когда как у другого разработчика этот код работает?

Tags: c, препроцессор

изучаю программу `unrealircd`. там есть такой код.

```
                list_for_each_entry(client, &lclient_list, lclient_node)
                        (void) send_queued(client);
```

я посмотрел где опеределен этот дефайн.

```
#define list_for_each_entry(pos, head, member)                          \
        for (pos = list_entry((head)->next, typeof(*pos), member);      \
             &pos->member != (head);    \
             pos = list_entry(pos->member.next, typeof(*pos), member))
```

и я так понимаю что этот код рабочий. а у меня пишет ошибку. вот что я написал для теста.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct p {
        int a;
        struct p *next;
};

#define list_for_each_entry ( p, head )  \
        for ( p = head; p != NULL; p = p->next )

int main ( ) {
        struct p *head, *p;
        head = calloc ( 1, sizeof ( struct p ) );
        p = head;

        int i = 0;
        for ( p = head; i < 3; i++, p = p->next ) {
                p->a = i; 
                p->next = calloc ( 1, sizeof ( struct p ) );
        }
        p->next = NULL;

        p = NULL;

        list_for_each_entry ( p, head )
                printf ( "pos %d\n", p->a );
}
```

пишет ошибку.

```
gcc main.c -o test
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:10:2: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘for’
  for ( p = head; p != NULL; p = p->next )
  ^
main.c:26:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘list_for_each_entry’
  list_for_each_entry ( p, head )
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите пробел после имени макроса:

```
#define list_for_each_entry( p, head )  \
    for ( p = head; p != NULL; p = p->next )
```

Препроцессор считает, что `( p, head )` — это не аргументы макроса, а текст подстановки, поэтому после подстановки макрос разворачивается в

```
( p, head )
    for ( p = head; p != NULL; p = p->next)
```

После выражения `( p, head )` нет точки запятой, т. е. не образуется отдельный *statement*, поэтому компилятор диагностирует синтаксическую ошибку.

Comment: ого. спасибо...